# time-dependent inflection points

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

For a function $u:\mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, let $\bar{x}$ be an inflection point of $u_0(x):=u(x,0)$ to the right of its maximum. Further, let the inflection point evolve with time $t\mapsto\bar{x}(t)$ such that $\bar{x}(0)=\bar{x}$. Surely we then have $(u_0)_{xx}(\bar{x}(0))=u_{xx}(\bar{x}(0),0)=0$, but why is it true that $u_{xx}(\bar{x}(t),t)=0$ for all $t\geq 0$? I'm assuming this follows since $(\bar{x}(t),t)$ is also an inflection point of $u$, but I can't see why this is true.

For reference, I'm trying to understand the proof of Lemma 6 from this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09000.pdf. It is in this proof that I encountered the claim above.

I'm pretty confused about the entire idea of a time-dependent inflection point, and in particular, about going from an inflection point of a function of a single variable, i.e. an inflection point of $u_0(x)$, to an inflection point of the two-variable function $u$. I would really appreciate a clear, pedagogical answer if possible.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably, their definition of "time-dependent inflection point" should be understood as: $X$ is an inflection point at time $t$ if $u_{xx}(X,t)=0$. In that case $u_{xx}(\bar{x}(t),t)=0$ is simply the statement that "the inflection point evolves with time $t\mapsto \bar{x}(t)$ such that $\bar{x}(0)=\bar{x}$." (The purpose of the initial condition is presumably because multiple inflection points could exist at a given time, but only one evolves from the initial one as $t$ is varied.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks for the suggestion. I'll operate using the definition you mentioned for now. Wish they would've just written an explicit definition, since this seems to be somewhat of a nonstandard notion.